# Import and Combine multiple csv files but change delimiter to | in R

Tags: r

I know theres a lot of code that can import and combine multiple CSV files, but I need to also change the delimiter.

The code I'm using is

```
df <- list.files() %>% 
  lapply(read_csv) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

Is there a way to alter that code to specify the delimiter as |?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it more easier way than additionally using `bind_rows`

```r
library(readr)

paths <- list.files()

read_delim(paths, id = "path", delim = "|")
```

this will automatically read all the files in the paths obtained by `list.files` and bind them

Answer (score 1):

use `pmap` function if you need different separators in your csv files

```
require(purrr)
setwd('d:/tmp/SO_csvfiles/')
flist <- list.files()
seps <- c(',',';','|')
data.list <- pmap(list(flist, seq_along(flist)), function(fname, .index) {
  read.csv(fname, sep=seps[.index])
})
bind_rows(data.list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`lapply()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply) function accepts a `...` (dot-dot-dot) argument and passes that on to FUN ([dot-dot-dot explained](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html?q=...#fun-dot-dot-dot)), so

```r
df <- list.files() %>% 
  lapply(read_delim, delim = "|") %>%
  bind_rows
```

is how you set the delimiter to "|" for the `read_delim()` function.

Another potential alternative is to identify the files you're interested in and import them using [`vroom()`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/) which will guess the delimiter and also provide an "ID" column indicating which rows came from which csv (although obviously you don't need to use this if you don't want):

```r
library(fs)
library(vroom)

file_list <- fs::dir_ls(path = "/your_path/to_your_files", glob = "*.txt")
data <- vroom::vroom(file_list, id = "filename")
```